# Retrieve system audio through HTML

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Is there a decent way to capture the audio stream of a user and record it?

I've only seen the getUserMedia() functions, but those seem to be only usable with the Mic or webcam.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use getUserMedia to do this. This will invoke a dialog on the client so user can confirm it's ok to record.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia

There is also record media api to do the actual recording. Not sure how ready it is, but it seem to work with FF.

http://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/

Comment: It was my impression that you could only get microphone audio, not system audio through this stream. Is that not the case?

Comment: @Jake i think that is correct, but isn't that what you want when you say "audio stream of a user"? Not sure how you can record the user wo mic :)

Comment: Well if they were playing music and wanted to send that stream through webRTC.

Comment: @Jake ahh.. i dont think that is possible